# Is there anything wrong with keeping random intercept and slope terms that are perfectly correlated with oneanother?

Tags: r, mixed-model, psychometrics

I am following the advice to "keep it maximal", and am analyzing the results from several psycholinguistic experiments. My main interest is in the fixed effects, with the random effect terms in there to provide a better test of these fixed effects.

That being said, I would like to keep things simple and, as much as possible, have the same analyses in each experiment.

In several of the experiments my random subject intercepts and slopes are perfectly, negatively correlated.

Given everything I said, would I be committing a cardinal sin by keeping both of them in the model?

Some details: I am the glmer function in R. I have only one fixed effect. I am running a logistic regression.

Comment: What might "keep it maximal" actually mean?

Comment: Within the context of psycholinguistic experiments when the main interest is in the fixed effects, that there are good reasons to always use the maximally complex random effects structure.

This is the article: http://idiom.ucsd.edu/~rlevy/papers/barr-etal-2013-jml.pdf

Comment: We really need more detail here. Try subtracting the mean from your predictor variable and see what happens.

Comment: I'm not sure about the keep it maximal recommendation since these issues almost always occur when one of the members of the correlation has very low variance. In that case, removing it would have little to no effect on the test conservativeness.